# Possibilidade de usar o MAX em campos DateTime expressão Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, expressões-lambda, filtro

Existe a possibilidade de usar o `MAX` em consultas de expressão `lambdas`, por exemplo:

Gostaria de pegar todos os registro com idade de 18 anos e pegar o único último registro inserido no banco de dados, ou seja, com a maior data de cadastro.

```
Lista.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Idade.Equals(18) && x.DataCadastro);
```

Comment: Você quer pegar dois resultados?

Comment: Essa lista é um campo auto - incremento ?

Comment: Em lambda existe o Max também: `Lista.Max(x => x.DataCadastro)`, supondo que a Lista já está filtrada (idade)

Answer (score 1):

As soluções acima não resolveram meu problema, pois pretendo trazer realmente apenas um registro, por isso gostaria de usar o MAX, e caso eu use o MAX que contém no IEnumerable ele traz apenas o resultado do campo que estou realizando o max, ou seja o campo DataCadastro, sendo que preciso do registro inteiro da lista.

Resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma.

```
Lista.Where(x => x.Idade.Equals(18)).OrderByDescending(x => x.DataCadastro).FirstOrDefault();
```